# What is the difference between this wireless flash trigger and wireless flash controller?

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, yongnuo

I am trying to work out what I need to trigger my flashes, which are Yongnuo YN-565EX (Nikon).

I have found two options, but I am not sure if I need both. One is a "wireless flash controller" (Yongnuo YN-560-TX) and the other is a wireless flash trigger (Yongnuo YN-622N). I'm not sure what the difference is. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 1):

One attaches to and sends the signal from your camera. It is what we call the controller or transmitter. The other receives that signal and is attached to the flash and is called the receiver or trigger.

Transceivers are able to do both functions: they can act as a transmitter when attached to the camera or as a receiver when attached to the flash.

Also note that some wireless systems use optical signals (pre-flashes) to communicate with the off camera flashes, while other systems use radio signals to communicate. The receiver built in to your YN565EX is an optical one. That is why you would need to attach a radio receiver to it for use with the YN-560TX which transmits via radio, rather than optical, signals.

Comment: Many Thanks, so does that mean I need both? If yes, I am buying 2 speedlights so do I need 2 receivers and one controller?

Comment: Because you are planning to use TTL, yes.  You will need an aditional transceiver for your second flash.  If you want to go manual, then you can set your second flash to slave mode S2 and it will fire automatically at whatever power you set it to when the main flash goes off.

Comment: @MikeV He doesn't necessarily need a second *transceiver*, a simple *receiver* on the correct frequency would also work.

Comment: @MichaelClark  You are correct.  A receiver that will receive full TTL info would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not mentioning the secific models I'm only adressing the main question:

> What is the difference between this wireless flash trigger and wireless flash controller?

A flash trigger, well simply trigers one or several flashes. In some cases it can wake up them, but that is it.

A flash controller can change the output power, of one or several fhashes, normally distribuited into groups. So you can set "A" group at 1/2 power, "B" to 1/8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The YN-560-TX can only control the power remotely on a YN-560III or YN-560IV. Using it with a YN-565EX will only work if the YN-565EX is on an RF-602 Rx unit, or RF-603, RF-603II, or RF-605 transceiver, and the only control it can offer is firing the flash in sync.  (With the RF-605, however, you can also use groups control to turning firing on/off for that specific flash).

The YN-622C transceiver is probably the best companion for the YN-568EX if you want to take advantage of the iTTL, FP flash, and remote power control capabilities of the YN-565EX.

To remotely control a YN-565EX over radio with TTL/FP capability with YN triggers, you'd need a YN-622N transceiver to act as a receiver, and either a second YN-622N or YN-622N-TX to act as the on-camera transmitter unit.  The YN-622N-TX dedicated transmitter is much easier to use than a YN-622N transceiver because it has an LCD display to show the flash's settings, while the transceiver only has a few LEDs to indicate channel, group, and power settings.

The YN-565EX (and Mk II) have CLS slave capability, so you don't have to use radio triggers, if your camera body has a built-in CLS commander in the pop-up flash.  They also have two "dumb" optical slave modes (S1/S2) which can act like Nikon's SU-4 mode to be set off by any pop-up flash, without using CLS.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update : TX versions of both 622(C/N) and 560 are available now at http://stores.ebay.com/hkyongnuophotoequipment/

– The YN-622-TX and YN-622C receivers are a full ETTL and Remote Manual system.
– The YN560-TX and YN-560 III flash units are a Remote Manual system only.
- See more at: http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn560-tx-to-yn-622c-compatibility-added